# How to autofill and increment a field in a subform during a new record click event?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form and a subform. I have a button that adds a new record to the subform.

I want to be able to click on new record and autofill the first field in the subform by one everytime. One of my trials is below with Nz() and DMax().

I have also tried FOR LOOPS and some BEFORE_INSERT situations.

The name of my field is [Time Hour] and the TextBox name for the field in the subform is "TimeHour".

```
Private Sub NextHour_Click()
Me.Hourly_Sub_subform.SetFocus
RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
If Me.NewRecord Then
On Error Resume Next
Me!TimeHour.Value = Nz(DMax("[Time Hour]", "[Hourly Subform Query]", " "), 
0) + 1
End If
End Sub
```

The max I want to go is 12 records. I want the code to be able to handle Null values, for if there are no records and the subform has to start at 1. As well as, being able to have a new user come up and add a new record in the middle of the subform and click the new record button to autofill whatever the number needs to be.

Here is my Before insert event:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(CANCEL As Integer)
If Me.NewRecord = True And Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 12 Then
MsgBox "Only 12 Records can be added for 12 hours per shift.", 
vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "ff&esize"
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
End If
End Sub
```

P.S. If you can add it, I want to also prevent the users from typing in duplicate values for field [Time Hour].

Overall, my parameters for the subform are:
 Only 12 records.
 New record click event will add numbers 1 - 12 to field [Time Hour].
 No duplicates for those hours.
 Also no going out of order i.e. 3 -> 7 it has to be 3 -> 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have - error message, wrong results, nothing happens?

Comment: There is no error but the top code doesn't work. It's supposed to add a new record with the field autofilled with a number. This result only creates new records with the field "BLANK". The Before_Insert code is correct but if anyone finds a way to add more code to resolve my issues then please use that.

Comment: You set focus to subform then use Me. Since code is behind main form Me is referencing main form, not subform. Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and see what error message you get. Suggest using indentation in code to make it more readable.